# in C# Form App exe, An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: c#, server, tcp, client, exe

[SCREENSHOT OF TCP SERVER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZTPU.jpg)I have a TCP server application as an exe, which runs on Windows Server 2012 R2 operating system and uses a specific port. I have allowed the necessary permissions for this port in the firewall, and I have even disabled the firewall entirely. I use this server to receive data from a service and process it in another application. In my code, I'm encountering the error mentioned in the title. When I run the application as an exe, it works for one day, but after one day, it stops receiving connections. However, when I run it in debug mode, I encounter the error with every incoming connection.Screenshot of the exe application:

I tried allowing the port through the firewall, but it didn't work. The application stops receiving connections after one day. I have to restart it every day.The code that produces the error is as follows.

```
   `private void Send(TcpClient tcpClient, byte[] datagram)
    {
        if (tcpClient == null)`your text
            throw new ArgumentNullException("tcpClient");

        if (datagram == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("datagram");

        try
        {
            NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            if (stream.CanWrite)
            {
                stream.BeginWrite(datagram, 0, datagram.Length, HandleDatagramWritten, tcpClient);
            }
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }`
```